# Wordpress Post's Category Name without capitalisation

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am using the following piece of code in wordpress to retrieve the name of the categorys however it is capitalising the category names.

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category):?>
        <button data-filter=".<?php echo $category->name;?>">Button</button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The output I am getting is be this

```
<button data-filter=".Category">Button</button>
```

But I need it to output as

```
<button data-filter=".category">Button</button>
```

Thanks and hopefully I find a solution.

Comment: strtolower can help from what i see

Comment: rtfm http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category):?>
    <button data-filter=".<?php echo strtolower($category->name);?>">Button</button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`strtolower()` is a php function that

> Returns string with all alphabetic characters converted to lowercase.

Comment: Perfect!  I'll accept it after 8mins when it lets me :)